# Nokogiri XML Searching

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I've tried reading the Nokogiri docs, etc, but I've came to a road block.

I get an XML output similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns1:getPoliciesResponse xmlns:ns1="http://policy.api.control.r1soft.com/">
      <return>
        <CDPId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx</CDPId>
        <description/>
        <diskSafeID>bcb68765-a719-4291-912d-2e6af485ea24</diskSafeID>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <id>cdb65427-d6f4-4a89-9f77-8763e22dc74b</id>
        <lastReplicationRunTime>2013-06-12T13:29:40.105-05:00</lastReplicationRunTime>
        <name>pstueck-passenger ondemand</name>
        <replicationScheduleFrequencyType>ON_DEMAND</replicationScheduleFrequencyType>
        <state>OK</state>
      </return>
      <return>
        <CDPId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx</CDPId>
        <description/>
        <diskSafeID>e8e13555-f577-40d2-99c8-fa8a019d3b55</diskSafeID>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <id>7f55f8d6-92a9-4b14-bff4-631559d92259</id>
        <lastReplicationRunTime>2013-06-16T22:00:04.918-05:00</lastReplicationRunTime>
        <name>pstueck-mysql daily</name>
        <nextReplicationRunTime>2013-06-17T22:00:00-05:00</nextReplicationRunTime>
        <replicationScheduleFrequencyType>DAILY</replicationScheduleFrequencyType>
        <state>ALERT</state>
        <warnings>Policy last completed with alerts</warnings>
      </return>
    </ns1:getPoliciesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But I have a large # of 'return' sections that get displayed back.  I'm trying to use the .search at the end of string.  I'm only wanting it to return the entire 'return' section for a given 'name'.  Anyone have any tips?

Current Code:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  http.auth.basic "#{opts['api_username']}", "#{opts['api_password']}"
  wsdl.document = "#{opts['api_url']}/Policy?wsdl"
end

getPolicyInformation = client.request :getPolicies
getPolicyInformation = Nokogiri::XML(getPolicyInformation.to_xml)
print getPolicyInformation
```

I'm wanting to return everything in the `<return>` section if I search for a specified `<name>`.  Example:  I only want to see the information relating to `<name>pstueck-passenger ondemand</name>`, but the entire `<return>` section that contains that.

Comment: What does your Ruby code look like so far? :)

Comment: `client = Savon::Client.new do
      http.auth.basic "#{opts['api_username']}", "#{opts['api_password']}"
      wsdl.document = "#{opts['api_url']}/Policy?wsdl"
    end

    getPolicyInformation = client.request :getPolicies
    getPolicyInformation = Nokogiri::XML(getPolicyInformation.to_xml)
    print getPolicyInformation`

Comment: Sorry to bother, but could your code be added to your original question?  *(This will hopefully help in getting an answer to your question...)*  And welcome to SO!

Comment: If you have multiple `<return>` tags, then your XML sample isn't valid/correct. It needs a wrapping tag to surround the `<return>` tags. Please fix your sample to correctly reflect the XML you're parsing.

Comment: @theTinMan Updated my output to reflect the "full" output from Nokogiri.

Comment: Savon automatically parses the response into a hash. Why not use that? Otherwise you're needlessly parsing the XML twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath to identify a node with a particular value and then specify that an ancestor element is of interest by doing something like the following:

```
require 'nokogiri'

document = <<-XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns1:getPoliciesResponse xmlns:ns1="http://policy.api.control.r1soft.com/">
      <return>
        <CDPId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx</CDPId>
        <description/>
        <diskSafeID>bcb68765-a719-4291-912d-2e6af485ea24</diskSafeID>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <id>cdb65427-d6f4-4a89-9f77-8763e22dc74b</id>
        <lastReplicationRunTime>2013-06-12T13:29:40.105-05:00</lastReplicationRunTime>
        <name>pstueck-passenger ondemand</name>
        <replicationScheduleFrequencyType>ON_DEMAND</replicationScheduleFrequencyType>
        <state>OK</state>
      </return>
      <return>
        <CDPId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx</CDPId>
        <description/>
        <diskSafeID>e8e13555-f577-40d2-99c8-fa8a019d3b55</diskSafeID>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <id>7f55f8d6-92a9-4b14-bff4-631559d92259</id>
        <lastReplicationRunTime>2013-06-16T22:00:04.918-05:00</lastReplicationRunTime>
        <name>pstueck-mysql daily</name>
        <nextReplicationRunTime>2013-06-17T22:00:00-05:00</nextReplicationRunTime>
        <replicationScheduleFrequencyType>DAILY</replicationScheduleFrequencyType>
        <state>ALERT</state>
        <warnings>Policy last completed with alerts</warnings>
      </return>
    </ns1:getPoliciesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(document)
ns = { 'soap' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'ns1' => "http://policy.api.control.r1soft.com/" }
ret = doc.xpath('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:getPoliciesResponse/return/name[text()="pstueck-passenger ondemand"]/ancestor::return', ns)

puts ret.count
puts ret.at('replicationScheduleFrequencyType').text
```

#### EDIT

Updated to reflect updated XML body in question. Now handles namespaces.

Comment: I don't have any `<returns>` within the XML output.

Comment: Sorry, @PatrickStueck. It looks like the XML body in your question was edited at some point. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS to find the node:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns1:getPoliciesResponse xmlns:ns1="http://policy.api.control.r1soft.com/">
      <return>
        <CDPId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx</CDPId>
        <description/>
        <diskSafeID>e8e13555-f577-40d2-99c8-fa8a019d3b55</diskSafeID>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <id>7f55f8d6-92a9-4b14-bff4-631559d92259</id>
        <lastReplicationRunTime>2013-06-16T22:00:04.918-05:00</lastReplicationRunTime>
        <name>pstueck-mysql daily</name>
        <nextReplicationRunTime>2013-06-17T22:00:00-05:00</nextReplicationRunTime>
        <replicationScheduleFrequencyType>DAILY</replicationScheduleFrequencyType>
        <state>ALERT</state>
        <warnings>Policy last completed with alerts</warnings>
      </return>
      <return>
        <CDPId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx</CDPId>
        <description/>
        <diskSafeID>bcb68765-a719-4291-912d-2e6af485ea24</diskSafeID>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <id>cdb65427-d6f4-4a89-9f77-8763e22dc74b</id>
        <lastReplicationRunTime>2013-06-12T13:29:40.105-05:00</lastReplicationRunTime>
        <name>pstueck-passenger ondemand</name>
        <replicationScheduleFrequencyType>ON_DEMAND</replicationScheduleFrequencyType>
        <state>OK</state>
      </return>
    </ns1:getPoliciesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
EOT

return_tag = doc.at('return name[text()="pstueck-passenger ondemand"]').parent

puts return_tag.to_xml
```

Which outputs:

```
<return>
  <CDPId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx</CDPId>
  <description/>
  <diskSafeID>bcb68765-a719-4291-912d-2e6af485ea24</diskSafeID>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <id>cdb65427-d6f4-4a89-9f77-8763e22dc74b</id>
  <lastReplicationRunTime>2013-06-12T13:29:40.105-05:00</lastReplicationRunTime>
  <name>pstueck-passenger ondemand</name>
  <replicationScheduleFrequencyType>ON_DEMAND</replicationScheduleFrequencyType>
  <state>OK</state>
</return>
```

Nokogiri supports both XPath and CSS. I find CSS easier to read.

I used the `at` method to find the first matching occurrence, and to show that it was the first matching, I swapped the order of the two `<return>` blocks. `at` is the same as `search(...).first` so when you're looking for the first instance of something in a document `at` is the way to go.

Nokogiri is usually smart enough to know the difference between XPath and CSS selectors, so we can use the generic `at` and `search`. If you need to force CSS or XPath parsing because the selector is gender-unspecific, you can use the specific `css` or `xpath` or `at_css` or `at_xpath` respectively. They're all documented in the [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) docs.

`parent` is necessary because we want the parent of the selected node, which was `<name>`. I just slammed it into reverse and backed up a block. That is easier to do in XPath, where we can use `..` to point to the parent node.